# Seg fault when trying to initialize a stringstream from string

Tags: c++, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

The following problem occurs on the Arduino for Esp8266.
This is a simple sketch that reproduces the problem. The program will run until we set the debug_stop = true via the GDBStub, then it will beak when trying to initialize the stringstream.

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <GDBStub.h>

#include <string>
#include <sstream>

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(115200);

    gdbstub_init();
}

bool debug_stop = true;

void loop() {

    Serial.println("Running");
    delay(100);

    // set debug_stop = false from GDB in order to continue
    if (debug_stop == true) return; 

     std::stringstream ss("hello");
}
```

After attaching with the GDBStub, trying to execute the `std::stringstream ss("hello");`
 results in a segmentation fault:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x40235268 in std::type_info::operator== (__arg=..., 
    this=0x402695c4 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/typeinfo:123
123 ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/typeinfo: No such file or directory.
```

This is the generated back trace (at least some lines, it extends over 600 lines and more).

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x4023659c in std::type_info::operator== (__arg=..., 
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/typeinfo:123
#1  0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, 
    access_path=__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info::__contained_public, 
    dst_type=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, 
    obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0x40269144 <typeinfo for std::locale::facet>, 
    src_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#2  0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, 
    access_path=__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info::__unknown, dst_type=0x3fff0be0 <std::cout+4>, 
    obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, src_type=0x3fff0bdc <std::cout>, 
    src_ptr=0x3fff0868 <__gnu_internal::buf_cout_sync>, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#3  0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=1073645236, 
    dst_type=0x3ffffa20, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0x3ffffa30, src_ptr=0x190001, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#4  0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=1073666608, 
    dst_type=0x3ffffaa0, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, src_type=
    0x40202215 <init_done()+29>, src_ptr=0xffffe6fc, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#5  0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=1946157057, 
    dst_type=0x66336a4a, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0x7a686a76, src_ptr=0xdfbd4764, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#6  0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=944788293, 
    dst_type=0x5f363632, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0x324f43, src_ptr=0x3fff2a30, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#7  0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=511, 
    dst_type=0xffffff04, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0xffff0001, src_ptr=0x3fff0358 <g_cont+4008>, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#8  0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=4294967295, 
    dst_type=0xffffffff, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0xffffffff, src_ptr=0xffffffff, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#9  0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=4294967295, 
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
    dst_type=0xffffffff, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0xffffffff, src_ptr=0xffffffff, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#10 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=4294967295, 
    dst_type=0xffffffff, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0xffffffff, src_ptr=0xffffffff, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#11 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=4294967295, 
    dst_type=0xffffffff, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0xffffffff, src_ptr=0xffffffff, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#12 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=4294967295, 
    dst_type=0xffffffff, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0xffffffff, src_ptr=0x36b8f604, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#13 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=4294967295, 
    dst_type=0xffffffff, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0xffffffff, src_ptr=0xffffffff, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#14 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=32, 
    dst_type=0x20, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, src_type=0x90, 
    src_ptr=0x4010f000, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#15 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=65534, 
    dst_type=0x0, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, src_type=0x0, 
    src_ptr=0x71490338, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#16 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=1073742067, 
    dst_type=0x4000e328, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, src_type=0x0, 
    src_ptr=0x506340, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#17 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=1953546291, 
    dst_type=0xf0b3f641, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0x21002030, src_ptr=0x0, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#18 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, 
    access_path=__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info::__unknown, dst_type=0x0, 
    obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, src_type=0x0, src_ptr=0x0, 
    result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
#19 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, 
    access_path=__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info::__unknown, dst_type=0x0, 
    obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, src_type=0x0, src_ptr=0x0, 
    result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#20 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, 
    access_path=__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info::__unknown, dst_type=0x0, 
    obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, src_type=0x0, src_ptr=0x0, 
    result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#21 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, 
    access_path=__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info::__unknown, dst_type=0x0, 
    obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, src_type=0x0, src_ptr=0x0, 
    result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#22 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=1073743256, 
    dst_type=0x3fffc000, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0x4000dc44, src_ptr=0x24, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#23 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=4194304, 
    dst_type=0xffffff, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0x7ff00000, src_ptr=0xcaa1ffce, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#24 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=20537830, 
    dst_type=0x41091129, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0xa1799169, src_ptr=0xd13022f0, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#25 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=3356416000, 
    dst_type=0x10ddc031, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0x5610ffd0, src_ptr=0xd02022f0, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#26 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, 
    access_path=__cxxabiv1::__class_type_info::__unknown, dst_type=0x61228159, 
    obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, src_type=0x30122c13, 
    src_ptr=0xc021e800, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#27 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=723661313, 
    dst_type=0x452a2222, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0x11080003, src_ptr=0x81d971c9, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
#28 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=13, 
    dst_type=0x3bd05ad, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0x6c604c0c, src_ptr=0x7440fb56, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#29 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=90780555, 
    dst_type=0xc5521579, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0x7642708, src_ptr=0xc052a014, result=...)
    at ../../../../../dl/gcc-xtensa/libstdc++-v3/libsupc++/vmi_class_type_info.cc:91
#30 0x402366a5 in __cxxabiv1::__vmi_class_type_info::__do_dyncast (
    this=0x40269c40 <typeinfo for std::ctype<char>>, src2dst=0, access_path=809509632, 
    dst_type=0x33b014b0, obj_ptr=0x3fff1778 <(anonymous namespace)::ctype_c>, 
    src_type=0xac0368c0, src_ptr=0x20688055, result=...)
```

I don't know how to further debug this problem. Any suggestion or idea?

The code is compile with the following flags:

```
 -DICACHE_FLASH -U__STRICT_ANSI__ " -c -w -Os -g -mlongcalls -mtext-section-literals -fno-rtti -falign-functions=4 -std=c++11 -MMD -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-exceptions  -DNONOSDK221=1 -DF_CPU=80000000L -DLWIP_OPEN_SRC -DTCP_MSS=536 -DLWIP_FEATURES=1 -DLWIP_IPV6=0   -DARDUINO=10605 -DARDUINO_ESP8266_NODEMCU -DARDUINO_ARCH_ESP8266 -DARDUINO_BOARD=\"ESP8266_NODEMCU\"  -DFLASHMODE_QIO  -DESP8266 -O0 -ggdb -std=c++11
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194018/discussion-on-question-by-woowapdabug-seg-fault-when-trying-to-initialize-a-stri).